# For loop to call a different function variable

Tags: r

I want call the `predict` function using different models to extract its predicted value.
I tried using `paste0` to call the right model but it doesn't work
for example:

```
model0 = lm(mpg ~ cyl + disp, data = mtcars)
model1 = lm(mpg ~ hp + drat, data = mtcars)
model2 = lm(mpg ~ wt + qsec, data = mtcars)

testdat0 = data.frame(cyl = 6, disp = 200)
testdat1 = data.frame(hp = 100, drat = 4)
testdat2 = data.frame(wt = 4, qsec = 20)

res = NULL
for (i in 1:3) {
  res = rbind(res, c(i-1, predict(paste0('model',i-1), newdata = paste0('testdat0',i-1))))
}
```

to do it manually

```
rbind(c(0, predict(model0, newdata = testdat0)), 
      c(1, predict(model1, newdata = testdat1)), 
      c(2, predict(model2, newdata = testdat2)))

              1
[1,] 0 21.02061
[2,] 1 24.40383
[3,] 2 18.13825
```

Another way I thought of doing this was to put the models and testdata in 2 separate `list()` and use a for loop to call them but that also didn't work. Is there another way of doing this or am I doing something wrong.. TIA

Comment: the predict you do only extracts the value for the first category (in your example the Mazda RX4) since you `c()` it to an index number. Is this what you want to do?

Comment: Maybe: `lm<-list(model0,model1,model2);lt<-list(testdat0,testdat1,testdat2);purrr::map2(lm,lt,predict)` or `mapply(predict, lm,lt)`

Comment: Yes it was intentional. This is just a silly example showing model comparison to predict mpg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My solution to your problem using a list and `sapply` so we don't need to define an external variable and `rbind()` to it over and over.

```
model0 = lm(mpg ~ cyl + disp, data = mtcars)
model1 = lm(mpg ~ hp + drat, data = mtcars)
model2 = lm(mpg ~ wt + qsec, data = mtcars)

testdat0 = data.frame(cyl = 6, disp = 200)
testdat1 = data.frame(hp = 100, drat = 4)
testdat2 = data.frame(wt = 4, qsec = 20)

#make list from sample data
data <- list(dat0=list(model=model0,test=testdat0),
             dat1=list(model=model1,test=testdat1),
             dat2=list(model=model2,test=testdat2))

#sapply over list, automatically converts to matrix
res <- sapply(data,function(dat) predict(dat$model,newdata=dat$test) )

> res
  dat0   dat1   dat2 
21.02061 24.40383 18.13825
```

Comment: This is certainly a much better method than using `rbind()` over and over again.

Comment: @AkselA Thanks for the heads-up fixed the comment.

Comment: sorry if this is a stupid question but I'm confused about the output of your 'res', what is it doing/showing? the expect mpg for each car based on the 3 models & data?

Comment: I'm sorry. I made a code error (`data` instead of `dat`) and did not notice that the result ist nonsensical (it's very early here). I fixed it and it should now show the exprected mpg for the values in `testdat`. // PS: To clarify what happened here: If you do not provide a `newdata` argument, predict will predict the original data with the model. Since `data$test` does not exist, R will handle the function as if `newdata` was omitted instead of throwing an error (I really don't like this behaviour). So it just predicted the data in `mtcars` with the model.

Answer (score 1):

To make your `for` loop work, you can make the below changes:

```
res = NULL
for (i in 1:3) {
  res = rbind(res, c(i-1, predict(eval(as.name(paste0('model',i-1)))), newdata = eval(as.name(paste0('testdat',i-1)))))
}
```